# user is anonymous despite the user is logged in

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, djoser

I hope you are fine.
I have a project using vue and django rest and I have done the authentication by djoser.
When a user logs in, a token would be set and the user can login to the website correctly but in views.py when I use self.request.user in get_queryset(self) function it says that the user is anonymous.
I will thank if anyone give me a piece of advice.
Thanks.

login axios code in vue js file:

```
login(){
        
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = ""
        localStorage.removeItem("token")

        const formData = {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }

        axios.post("/api/v1/token/login/", formData)
            .then(response => { 
                const token = response.data.auth_token

                this.$store.commit('setToken', token)
                
                axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Token " + token

                localStorage.setItem("token", token)  

            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error.response.data)
        })
    }
```

And in the setting.py I have put:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
```

}

and two lines of my urls.py about djoser:

```
path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
```

Comment: Can you add the content of the `views.py` file here?

Comment: The problem is that self.request.user in get_queryset(self) returns an anonymous user.                                                                                                                                                        
             class ComplaintViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ComplaintSerializer
    queryset = Complaint.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user).order_by("-created_at")

Comment: Hi, it would be really helpful if you pasted the code that you have written, and also to publish what are you trying etc. The more details, the best chances to get some help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added more details of my code in the part of my question that is in the top of the page; These are everything about my login and the login is done correctly and completely but the problem is that the self.request.user is anonymous

Comment: Please add the content of the views.py file not in the comment section but in your post.

Comment: Excuse me is it possible to help me to find the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `permission_classes` attribute.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class ComplaintViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ComplaintSerializer
    queryset = Complaint.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    ...
```

Comment: I have just tried what you said but now the error is 401 unauthorized. I think you didn't understand me. I mean that right now a user has logged in to the website but the self.request.user give me an anonymous user that is not authenticated

Comment: Then you must be using the authenticated API incorrectly.

Comment: Is it possible to help me to solve that please?

Comment: What URL did you use for login?

Comment: I have added more details of my code in the part of my question that is in the top of the page; These are everything about my login and the login is done correctly and completely nut the problem is that the self.request.user is anonymous

Comment: Excuse me is it possible to help me to find the solution please?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having the same problem...